# WPF Popup - How to close a WPF popup when the ESC key is pressed

Tags: c#, wpf, popup

I have a popup named "ContextPopup" defined in a ResourceDictionary as follows:

```
    <ControlTemplate x:Key="UXIconComboBoxControlTemplate" TargetType="{x:Type controls:UXIconComboBox}" >
    <ControlTemplate.Resources>
        <converters:IconComboBoxDropdownHorizontalOffsetMultiConverter x:Key="ComboBoxDropdownHorizontalOffsetConverter"/>
    </ControlTemplate.Resources>
    <Grid 
        x:Name="rootGrid"
        Width="{TemplateBinding HitAreaWidth}" 
        Height="{TemplateBinding HitAreaHeight}" 
        Background="{TemplateBinding Background}">
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <controls:ExtendedHitAreaButton 
            Grid.Row="0"
            x:Name="OpenPopupIconButton"
            IsDefault="True"
            Style="{StaticResource UXIconComboBoxButtonStyle}">
             <controls:ExtendedHitAreaButton.Triggers>
                <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="Button.Click">
                    <EventTrigger.Actions>
                        <BeginStoryboard>
                            <Storyboard>
                                <BooleanAnimationUsingKeyFrames 
                                    Storyboard.TargetName="ContextPopup" 
                                    Storyboard.TargetProperty="IsOpen">
                                    <DiscreteBooleanKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0.25" Value="True" />
                                </BooleanAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                            </Storyboard>
                        </BeginStoryboard>
                    </EventTrigger.Actions>
                </EventTrigger>
            </controls:ExtendedHitAreaButton.Triggers>
        </controls:ExtendedHitAreaButton>

       <Popup 
           x:Name="ContextPopup"
           Grid.Row="1" 
           Placement="Bottom"
           PlacementTarget="{Binding ElementName=OpenPopupIconButton}"
           StaysOpen="False"
           PreviewKeyDown="ContextPopup_PreviewKeyDown">
           <Popup.HorizontalOffset>
               <MultiBinding Converter="{StaticResource ComboBoxDropdownHorizontalOffsetConverter}">
                   <Binding ElementName="OpenPopupIconButton" Path="ActualWidth"/>
                   <Binding ElementName="PopupListBox" Path="ActualWidth"/>
               </MultiBinding>
           </Popup.HorizontalOffset>
            <ListBox 
                x:Name="PopupListBox" 
                ItemsSource="{Binding ItemsSource, RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}"
                ItemTemplate="{Binding ItemTemplate, RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}"
                Loaded="PopupListBox_OnLoaded"
                KeyboardNavigation.IsTabStop="True"
                KeyboardNavigation.TabNavigation="Continue"
                BorderThickness="0"/>
       </Popup>
    </Grid>
    <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
        <MultiDataTrigger>
            <MultiDataTrigger.Conditions>
                <Condition Binding="{Binding IconComboBoxSemanticColorType}" Value="Default"/>
                <Condition Binding="{Binding Path=IsOpen, ElementName=ContextPopup}" Value="True" />
            </MultiDataTrigger.Conditions>
            <Setter Property="Background" Value="{DynamicResource BrushIconComboBox_Popup_Open_Background}" />
        </MultiDataTrigger>
    </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
</ControlTemplate>
```

The Popup has a PreviewKeyDown method called "ContextPopup_PreviewKeyDown" that is defined in a ResourceDictionary code-behind file as follows:

```
private void ContextPopup_PreviewKeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{
    var popupControl = sender as Popup;

    if (e.Key == Key.Escape)
    {
        popupControl.IsOpen = false;
    }
}
```

When the popup is displayed, I press the ESC button and have verified that the ContextPopup_PreviewKeyDown method is called and the popupControl.IsOpen property is set to false, but the popup does not close.

Can anyone explain why the popup does not close and what to do about it.

Thanks for any help.

Comment: I guess you should remove the animation to open the Popup and replace it with a simple trigger. Otherwise you would have to trigger a second animation that sets IsOpen to false (to revert the first animation). Binding a ToggleButton to the IsOpen property will also do the trick.

Comment: The animation is a requirement, so I'll create a second animation and see if that works.

Comment: Why is this animation a requirement? It's just setting a boolean to true.

Comment: The length of time to close the popup is a requirement

Comment: You mean the delay? Because there is no analogues state change. it's a boolean. it just jumps from false to true. When you bind a ToggleButton to the IsOpen property you can set the bindings delay property to defer the property change. If you insist on the animation you should do it properly.

Comment: You should use the VisualStateManager on the parent control `UXIconComboBox`. Then define two visual states: "PopupOpen" and "PopupClosed". Define an animation that targets the Popup.IsOpen property for each state. Attach a routed command to the button that will open the Popup. Handle the routed command in the `UXIconComboBox` and transition the control to the "PopupOpen" state, which will trigger the related animation.

Comment: Then register the key down handler with the `UXIconComboBox`. Once "Esc" key is captured you transition the control to the "PopupClosed" state to trigger the closing animation. That's the most gracefull solution if you want to use animations with different trigger sources inside aparent control.

Comment: Can anyone explain why my current solution does not work?

Comment: I have already explained to you that the animation is preventing the property from accepting any values. I also provided you with solutions. Please refer to my answer to learn how to use the VisualStateManager to control animations.

Comment: Thank you for your explanation using the VisualStateManager. This solution works very well!! Vielen Dank!!

Comment: Now I have a different issue ... after the listbox is displayed, if I press the down-arrow, the listbox closes ... any idea why?

Comment: What are you doing inside `PopupListBox_OnLoaded`? Do you move any focus? You probably are navigating outside the Popup because the Popup/ListBox has not received keyboard focus.

Comment: I have updated my answer to show how to move keyboard focus inside the ListBox (or the first child element of the Popup in general) once the Popup is open. This prevents navigation outside the open Popup. Note that I needed to change the property type of PART_ContextPopup from UIElement to Popup.

Comment: Determined what was causing the listbox to close .... when the down arrow button is pressed to move to the next item in the list, it generates a LostFocus event on the previous item. I was using the LostFocus event to set the VisualStateManager.GoToState to "PopupClosed" .... so I just need to add a few condition checks to the LostFocus handler before I set the VisualStateManager.GoToState to "PopupClosed"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't modify the property value as long as a `Storyboard` is still animating it. Either stop the `Storyboard` explicitly or apply another animation to modify the value.

The following example uses the `VisualStateManager` to trigger the animations.

```xml
<ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type local:UXIconComboBox}">
  <Border Background="{TemplateBinding Background}"
          BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}"
          BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}">
    <VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
      <VisualStateGroup x:Name="PopupStates">
        <VisualState x:Name="PopupClosed">
          <Storyboard>
            <BooleanAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="PART_ContextPopup"
                                            Storyboard.TargetProperty="IsOpen">
              <DiscreteBooleanKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0.25"
                                       Value="False" />
            </BooleanAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
          </Storyboard>
        </VisualState>
        <VisualState x:Name="PopupOpen">
          <Storyboard>
            <BooleanAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="PART_ContextPopup"
                                            Storyboard.TargetProperty="IsOpen">
              <DiscreteBooleanKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0.25"
                                       Value="True" />
            </BooleanAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
          </Storyboard>
        </VisualState>
      </VisualStateGroup>
    </VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>

    <Grid>
      <Button x:Name="PART_OpenPopupIconButton" />
      <Popup x:Name="PART_ContextPopup"
             AllowsTransparency="True">
        <TextBox Text="Hello World!" />
      </Popup>
    </Grid>
  </Border>
</ControlTemplate>
```

```cs
public class UXIconComboBox : Control
{
  private ButtonBase? PART_OpenPopupIconButton { get; set; }
  private UIElement? PART_ContextPopup { get; set; }

  static UXIconComboBox() 
  {
    DefaultStyleKeyProperty.OverrideMetadata(typeof(UXIconComboBox), new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(typeof(UXIconComboBox)));
  }

  public override void OnApplyTemplate()
  {
    base.OnApplyTemplate();

    this.PART_OpenPopupIconButton = GetTemplateChild("PART_OpenPopupIconButton") as ButtonBase;
    this.PART_OpenPopupIconButton.Click += OpenPopupIconButton_Click;

    this.PART_ContextPopup = GetTemplateChild("PART_ContextPopup") as UIElement;
    this.PART_ContextPopup.PreviewKeyDown += ContextPopup_PreviewKeyDown;
  }

  protected void ContextPopup_PreviewKeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
  {
    if (e.Key == Key.Escape)
    {
      _ = VisualStateManager.GoToState(this, "PopupClosed", true);
    }
  }

  private void OpenPopupIconButton_Click(object sender, System.Windows.RoutedEventArgs e) 
    => _ = VisualStateManager.GoToState(this, "PopupOpen", true);
}
```